ngOnInit is called twice in angular component
After first time when i fire ng serve and open component everything works perfect, one time each request is called. Then i close component and open it again, ngOnInit is called twice.
I have inside my ngOnInit QueryDispatcher and CommandDispatcher so they called twice and also child component in html with his own request/response and his ngOninit called twice as well.
Any thoughts on that guys ?
Thanks
kisOnInit(getResponse: GetResponse) {
    this.modalService.getData();
    if (modalData && modalData.data.seostatudDokumentOid)
    {
      this.seostatudDokumentOid = modalData.data.seostatudDokumentOid;
      this.seostatudDokumentIdList.push(this.seostatudDokumentOid);
    }
    this.menetlusService.getCurrentMenetlus()
      .subscribe((menetlus) =>  this.menetlus = menetlus);

    this.kasutaja =  this.authService.currentUserValue;
    this.response = getResponse;

    this.queryDispatcher
      .dispatch(new GetMenetluseFailidRequest(this.menetlus.objektId,  this.dokumentObjektId), null, this.destroy$ )
      .pipe()
      .subscribe((value: GetMenetluseFailidResponse) => {
        this.failResponse = value.dokumendiFailList;
      });
}

so GetMenetluseFailidRequest is called twice for example


please share minimal reproducible code

When the component is destroyed, all subscriptions need to be unsubscribed!
If you do not unsubscribe, then even if you destroy the component the subscriptions will live and give you the impression that the subscribe is happening multiple times!
you can use the below reference code to stop this!
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
...

...
export class SomeComponent {

    private sub: Subscription = new Subscription();

    ...
    ngOnInit() {
        // add all the subscriptions to the sub to unsubscribe altogether
        this.sub.add(
             this.menetlusService.getCurrentMenetlus()
                 .subscribe((menetlus) =>  this.menetlus = menetlus);
        );
    }
    ...
    
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

}


Also you have 2 x subscribe there so you need to add both of them to the sub Subscription

Thanks guys, but it doesnt help. The thing is when we open it first time the main kisOnInit(getResponse: GetResponse) { request fires first, but when we close it and open again the other request now are before it.

@chivas have you subscribed and unsubscribe all the subscribe in your code?

Yes i did. Added to sub all my subscribes. Thanks for helping
